# How do I align children of <label> in ASP.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net

I wanna emulate this on .NET:

```
<label for="contact_name">
    Nombre
   <span class="color2">*</span>
</label>
<input type="text" name="contact_name" id="contact_name"
    value="" size="22" tabindex="3"
    class="validate[required,minSize[3],maxSize[100],custom[onlyLetterSp]]" />
```

I used:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblNombre" AssociatedControlID="txtNombre" Text="Nombre" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNombre" runat="server" />
```

But I need to use the class `color 2` on the `*`, and it must be at the side right side of `Nombre` and not below or something else. If I create a label on the side of the one that is associated to the textbox with the `*` and the class, the `*` its gonna show below. How do I align this perfectly?

Comment: If you add your CSS to the post we may be able to help you. I don't see how nor why the asterisk would go down by itself.

Comment: Color 2 is only this .color2 {color:#33bee5;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is just to keep using the `<label>` control instead of using a server control, assuming you don't need to access your label in the code.

```
<label for="<%= txtNombre.ClientID %>">
    Nombre <span class="color2">*</span>
</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNombre" runat="server" />
```

Or if you do need to access it from the server, you can still do it:

```
<%-- This line can go in the code-behind if you want --%>
<% lblNombre.Attributes["for"] = txtNombre.ClientID; %>

<label id="lblNombre" runat="server">
    Nombre <span class="color2">*</span>
</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNombre" runat="server" />
```

Actually, you can have HTML in your `Label`'s text, so this will also work:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblNombre" AssociatedControlID="txtNombre"
    Text="Nombre <span class='color2'>*</span>" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNombre" runat="server" />
```

Comment: I used the last one. I tried before to put the html directly into the Text attribute, but I think I missed either a < or > and gave me an error so I tried something else, but this works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're doing a required field implementation.

Add a class to the .net label - for ex `requiredlbl` & then in css

`.requiredlbl:after { content:" *";color:red; }`

EDIT - for color

```
<asp:Label ID="lblNombre" CssClass="requiredlbl" Text="Nombre" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but what do I do about the color?

Comment: Ok, I got it, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblNombre" AssociatedControlID="txtNombre" runat="server" >    
    Nombre: <font color="red">*</font>
    </asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNombre" runat="server" />
```